# XCTestCase for opening camera and photo library

Tags: ios, swift, xctest, xctestcase

I have written a reusable class for opening camera and photo library as below

```
class CameraAndPhotoManager: NSObject {
    var currentVC: UIViewController!
    
    func camera(vc: UIViewController) {
            currentVC = vc
            if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera){
                let myPickerController = UIImagePickerController()
                myPickerController.delegate = self
                myPickerController.sourceType = .camera
                myPickerController.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeImage as String, kUTTypeMovie as String]
                currentVC.present(myPickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
        
    func photoLibrary(vc: UIViewController) {
            currentVC = vc
            if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.photoLibrary){
                let myPickerController = UIImagePickerController()
                myPickerController.delegate = self
                myPickerController.sourceType = .photoLibrary
                myPickerController.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeImage as String, kUTTypeMovie as String, kUTTypeVideo as String]
                currentVC.present(myPickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
}
```

I need to write TestCases for opening camera and photo library. Any information on writing test cases related to camera or photo library? Any sample code will be helpful.

Comment: The most complex (and maybe not possible in a general case) is getting Permissions. Also, you should write XCUITest, not XCTest for such case. I wrote a bunch of unit tests (XCTest) for PHPhotoLibrary API, it worked only if permissions were added manually for an app. Also, it didn't have any access to UI (such as UIImagePickerController)

Comment: agree, i felt the same, but i thought there may be a way to access camera or photo library for testing purpose. Let us see if anyone have got any information regarding this.

Answer (score 2):

You can unit test this, but not with code that directly depends on global state. Instead, I'd recognize these as boundaries we want to control. Then design tests that let you specify what source types are available. The production code requires some changes to support this boundary.

For example, `CameraAndPhotoManager` can define a closure property. By default, the closure has the normal behavior for production code:

```
var isSourceTypeAvailable: (UIImagePickerController.SourceType) -> Bool =
    { UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable($0) }
```

Call this closure instead of directly calling `UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(_:)`. The unit tests will not check the default closure, so make sure to do a manual test to confirm that this change works.

Now test code can replace the closure. To test `present(_:animated:completion)`, use [ViewControllerPresentationSpy](https://github.com/jonreid/ViewControllerPresentationSpy). Then we can write two tests for each function.

```
func test_camera_withCameraUnavailable_shouldRememberCurrentVCButNotPresentImagePicker() throws {
    let presentationVerifier = PresentationVerifier()
    let sut = CameraAndPhotoManager()
    sut.isSourceAvailable = {
       guard case $0 == .camera else { return false } // Make sure it's camera
       return false // camera unavailable
    }
    let vc = UIViewController()

    sut.camera(vc: vc)

    XCTAssertTrue(sut.currentVC === vc, "Expected currentVC \(vc), but was \(sut.currentVC)"
    XCTAssertEqual(presentationVerifier.presentedCount, 0, "presented count")
}

func test_camera_withCameraAvailable_shouldRememberCurrentVCAndPresentImagePicker() throws {
    let presentationVerifier = PresentationVerifier()
    let sut = CameraAndPhotoManager()
    sut.isSourceAvailable = {
       guard case $0 == .camera else { return false }
       return true // camera available
    }
    let vc = UIViewController()

    sut.camera(vc: vc)

    XCTAssertTrue(sut.currentVC === vc, "Expected currentVC \(vc), but was \(sut.currentVC)"
    let nextVC: UIImagePickerController? = presentationVerifier.verify(
        animated: true,
        presentingViewController: vc
    )
    // Now examine the properties of nextVC. For example:
    XCTAssertEqual(nextVC?.sourceType, .camera, "sourceType")
}
```